# Многопоточность, блокировка доступа

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть приведенный ниже код, суть в том, что функции `Add()`, `Read()`, `Modify()`, `Remove()`, вызываются извне и в хаотичном порядке, с разным периодом во времени.

Уже сломал голову, подскажите с помощью какой технологии языка C# мне организовать одновременный доступ к разным элементам массива `MyList`? И чтобы во время удаления/добавления новых элементов, текущие процессы не сбивались с толку, например в потоке `ReadThread` в данную секунду обрабатывается 5ый элемент массива и в туже секунду потоком `RemoveThread` уничтожается 4ый, индекс 5ого измениться, как быть?

Делал объект `Lock` для каждой структуры свой и блокировал отдельные элементы `MyList`, но тоже не решило проблемы добавления, удаления.

```
class test
{
    //переменные
    List<MyStruct> MyList = new List<MyStruct>();
    //блокировка доступа
    Object Lock = new Object();

    //буфер и поток для обработки событий Add
    BlockingCollection<MyStruct> AddBuffer = new BlockingCollection<MyStruct>();
    Thread AddThread;

    //буфер и поток для обработки событий Read
    BlockingCollection<string> ReadBuffer = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    Thread ReadThread;

    //буфер и поток для обработки событий Modify
    BlockingCollection<MyStruct> ModifyBuffer = new BlockingCollection<MyStruct>();
    Thread ModifyThread;

    //буфер и поток для обработки событий Remove
    BlockingCollection<string> RemoveBuffer = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    Thread RemoveThread;

    //конструктор
    public test()
    {
        if(!AddThread.IsAlive)
        {
            AddThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AddBufferReader));
            AddThread.IsBackground = true;
            AddThread.Start();
        }

        if(!ReadThread.IsAlive)
        {
            ReadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadBufferReader));
            ReadThread.IsBackground = true;
            ReadThread.Start();
        }

        if(!ModifyThread.IsAlive)
        {
            ModifyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ModifyBufferReader));
            ModifyThread.IsBackground = true;
            ModifyThread.Start();
        }

        if(!RemoveThread.IsAlive)
        {
            RemoveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RemoveBufferReader));
            RemoveThread.IsBackground = true;
            RemoveThread.Start();
        }
    }

    //Добавляем 
    internal void Add(string Name, string InputString)
    {
        //добавляем имя структуры которую надо добавить
        AddBuffer.Add(new MyStruct(Name, InputString));
    }
    void AddBufferReader()
    {
        foreach(var MyStruct in AddBuffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            lock(Lock)
            {
                //некоторые условия, не все будет добавлено в MyList
                if(true)
                {
                    //add, add
                    MyList.Add(new MyStruct(MyStruct.Name, MyStruct.MyString));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Читаем
    internal void Read(string Name)
    {
        //добавляем имя структуры которую надо прочитать и вывести/обработать
        ReadBuffer.Add(Name);
    }
    void ReadBufferReader()
    {
        foreach(var Name in ReadBuffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            lock(Lock)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(MyList[i].Name == Name)
                    {
                        //долгие вычисления
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Изменяем
    internal void Modify(string Name, string NewString)
    {
        //добавляем имя структуры которую надо прочитать и вывести/обработать
        ModifyBuffer.Add(new MyStruct(Name, NewString));
    }
    void ModifyBufferReader()
    {
        foreach(var MyStruct in ModifyBuffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            lock(Lock)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(MyList[i].Name == MyStruct.Name)
                    {
                        //долгие вычисления
                        MyList[i] = new MyStruct(MyList[i].Name, MyStruct.MyString);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Удаляем
    internal void Remove(string Name)
    {
        //добавляем имя структуры которую надо удалить из MyList
        RemoveBuffer.Add(Name);
    }
    void RemoveBufferReader()
    {
        foreach(var Name in RemoveBuffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            lock(Lock)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(MyList[i].Name == Name)
                    {
                        //remove, remove
                        MyList.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct
    {
        internal string Name;
        internal string MyString;

        public MyStruct(string Name, string MyString)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.MyString = MyString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему бы просто не блокировать на время доступа коллекцию про помощи `lock`?

Comment: В коде который привел, я так и использую lock(), но не устраивает тем, что не возможно получить доступ сразу к нескольким элементам, для чтения, из-за общей блокировки которая предохраняет от изменения индекса элементов, при добавлении/удалении новых элементов. Подскажите в какую сторону мне "копать", что изучить?

Comment: Опишите словами задачу, которую пытаетесь решить.

Comment: Данные поступают в программу из вне, и без конкретной привязки по времени(может 1000 в секунду, может 0 в час). Определенную часть данных надо хранить неопределенное время, и при поступлении новых данных принимать решения относительно старых данных, просто прочитать, изменить, удалить. Из-за большого кол-ва поступающих данных сделал несколько потоков которые бы одновременно обрабатывали все поступающие данные и редактировали имеющиеся(сохраненные структуры) параллельно.

Comment: Ага, понял. Тогда вопрос нетривиальный, дайте подумать.

Comment: `MyList.Add(new MyStruct(MyStruct.Name, MyStruct.MyString))` - почему не просто `MyList.Add(MyStruct)`?

Comment: И вот еще: не нравятся мне ваши 4 потока! С таким подходом у вас операция Remove может выполниться раньше, чем операция Add над тем же самым элементом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Здравствуйте! У меня кст вот и возникла такая проблема, данные поступают, а поток Modify срабатывает раньше чем Add. Решением может быть только организации всего через один поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы начал с [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) или [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx):

В этой документации приведён полноценный пример использования. Краткая суть в том, что читать могут сразу несколько потоков. Писать может только один. Читающий поток может захотеть писать и тогда он запрашивает блокировку на запись , что предотвращает появление новых читателей, пока объект не освободится и не завершится запись. Читатели, на время, пока объект заблокирован и происходит запись, ждут. Максимальное время ожидания регулируется вами.

Для реализации более гранулированной блокировки вы можете объявить "корзины" для элементов, которые находятся в процессе чтения и "корзину" для элементов, находящихся в процессе правки, то есть использовать не один а два или более экземпляров `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Однако, будьте осторожны. Грануляция блокировок всегда черевата *мёртвыми* блокировками (**deadlock**).

Представьте, что в вашем MyList два объекта и вы решили блокировать их отдельно. К вам одновременно приходят два запроса. Один - на чтение, другой на запись.

1. Первый поток забрал первый элемент `MyList` на чтение.
2. Второй поток забрать второй элемент `MyList` на запись.
3. Первый поток начал ждать освобождения второго элемента. Он хочет его почитать.
4. Второй поток начал ждать окончания чтения первого элемента. Он хочет его исправить.

Вы в ж... я хотел сказать в **deadlock**-е. Именно по этому так полезно указывать конечное значение `timeout` при обращении к `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Ну или сразу согласиться, что экземпляр `ReaderWriterLockSlim` будет один и на запись будет блокироваться весь ресурс целиком. Тогда deadlock-и вам не страшны.

Comment: Спасибо! Видимо это то что нужно, только вот ради образовательного процесса не совсем мне понятно как там все реализуется, в смысле, ведь это все можно написать самому в коде, а я не понимаю как остановить/вывести из чтения "читающие потоки" дать доступ для изменения Коллекции и "отпустить" читающие потоки.

Comment: Смотрите пример кода в документации, на которую я прислал ссылку. `rwl.ReleaseReaderLock()` говорит, что чтение завершено.

Comment: Да, я изучил, взять и сделать по аналогии я смогу, хотелось бы в идеале понять как все это делать "руками".

Comment: Руками хлопотно. Всё построено на паре ManualResetEvent, одном AutoResetEvent, Interlocked и наборе счётчиков. Очень тонкий код.

Comment: Вот вариант реализации через монитор. http://readerwriterlockalt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReaderWriterLockAlt/ReaderWriterLockAlt.cs
Для меня это настолько неинтуитивно, что я бы не взялся это понять.

Comment: Кстати, я совсем забыл про `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, используйте лучше его.

Comment: Нашел ссылку на ReaderWriterLockSlim в описании ReaderWriterLock. Спасибо за код, где показано как это реализуется.

Comment: Смотрите сразу первоисточник: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/system/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs

В отличаи от `ReaderWriterLock`, код `ReaderWriterLockSlim` полностью на C#, читабелен.

Тому, кто в этом детально разберётся и сможет "просто" объяснить, я бы давал медаль, посмертно.

Answer (score 3):

Окей, вам по идее нужен fine-grained lock. То есть блокировка не на уровне всего списка, а на уровне одного элемента.

Кроме того, раз вы ищете элемент по ключу, имеет смысл воспользоваться `Dictionary`.

Для этого давайте оснастим элемент списка объектом для блокировки. Выйдет что-то такое:

```
class Wrapper<T> // это будет одновременно и обёртка, и объект для блокировки
{
    public T Value;
    public bool IsAlive = true;
}

Dictionary<string, Wrapper<MyStruct>> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, Wrapper<MyStruct>>;
object Lock = new object();

void AddItem(string key, MyStruct value)
{
    lock(Lock)
    {
        MyDict.Add(key, new Wrapper<MyStruct>() { Value = value });
    }
}

void ModifyItem(string key)
{
    Wrapper<MyStruct> wrapper;
    lock(Lock)
    {
        if (!MyDict.TryGetValue(key, out wrapper))
            return; // нет такого (уже)
    }
    // получить данные можно под внутренние блокировкой:
    MyStruct oldValue;
    lock (wrapper)
    {
        if (!wrapper.IsAlive)
            return;
        oldValue = wrapper.Value;
    }
    // теперь у нас есть данные, можно с ними долго работать
    /* тут длинные вычисления */
    // для модификации нужно залочить снова wrapper
    lock (wrapper)
    {
        if (!wrapper.IsAlive)
            return; // упс, наш элемент тем временем удалили
        wrapper.Value = newValue;
    }
}

void DeleteItem(string key)
{
    Wrapper<MyStruct> wrapper;
    lock(Lock)
    {
        if (!MyDict.TryGetValue(key, out wrapper))
            return; // нет такого (уже)
    }
    // модифицируем 
    lock (wrapper)
    {
        if (!wrapper.IsAlive)
            return;
        wrapper.IsAlive = false;
    }
    lock (Lock)
    {
        MyDict.RemoveKey(key);
    }
}
```

---

Если у вас зависимые данные, вам нужно для обработки залочить несколько элементов. Для этого, чтобы избежать deadlock'ов, имеет смысл лочить их в фиксированном порядке (например, по возрастанию ключа).

```
void ModifyItems(IEnumerable<string> keys)
{
    var materialKeys = keys.OrderBy(k => k).ToList();
    List<Wrapper<MyStruct>> wrappers = new List<Wrapper<MyStruct>>();
    bool lockSuccessful = true;
    lock(Lock)
    {
        Wrapper<MyStruct> wrapper;
        foreach (var key in materialKeys)
        {
            if (!MyDict.TryGetValue(key, out wrapper))
            {
                lockSuccessful = false;
                break;
            }
            wrappers.Add(wrapper);
            Monitor.Enter(wrapper);
        }
    }

    if (lockSuccessful)
    {
        // мы получили данные, работаем с ними
        /* тут длинные вычисления */
    }

    lock (Lock)
    {
        foreach (var key in materialKeys.Reverse())
        {
            Monitor.Exit(wrapper);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Если вам неинтересно в конце `ModifyItem` убедиться, что значение ещё живое, можно всё упростить.

```
Dictionary<string, MyStruct> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, MyStruct>();
object Lock = new object();

void AddItem(string key, MyStruct value)
{
    lock(Lock)
    {
        MyDict.Add(key, value);
    }
}

void ModifyItem(string key)
{
    MyStruct oldValue;
    lock(Lock)
    {
        if (!MyDict.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
            return; // нет такого (уже)
    }
    // теперь у нас есть данные, можно с ними долго работать
    /* тут длинные вычисления */
    // для модификации нужно залочить снова wrapper
    lock(Lock)
    {
        if (!MyDict.ContainsKey(key))
            return; // удалили тем временем
        MyDict[key] = newValue;
    }
}

void DeleteItem(string key)
{
    lock(Lock)
    {
        MyDict.RemoveKey(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45621/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).